NMaximize in Mathematica cannot find points that satisfy constraints
I have a strange behavior of NMaximize in Mathematica. In the following code, NMaximize cannot find points that satisfy constraints while 0 is an obvious point that satisfies. Could you help to resolve the issue?
vi = {2.1046684005357883`, 0.14074069882048335`, 0.4558990785854712`, 
   0.37740904060822933`, 0.6248725928164722`, 0.14229042026452854`, 
   0.9060513624670112`, 1.8764469484898794`, 0.14081659595046414`, 
   0.48083110867545864`, 1.6567094543238614`};
ti = {4.860305321058765`, 5.015178822494303`, 3.598507947183823`, 
   6.146717679061292`, 0.6811965864644947`, 0.`, 0.`, 
   8.376814349219385`, 6.126324460258949`, 2.305782947996135`, 
   3.6110584835517483`};
bi = 1.1090584523414149`;
prioritiesi = {3.`, 3.`, 3.`, 3.`, 3.`, 4.`, 3.`, 3.`, 3.`, 3.`, 3.`};
rankcounti = 11;
bmax = 1.251;

xstable = Array[xs, rankcounti];
output = NMaximize[{Sum[vi[[j]] xs[j], {j, 1, rankcounti}],
   Flatten[{Sum[
       xs[j]*(Max[ti[[j]] - ((prioritiesi[[j]] - 1) *bmax), 0]), {j, 
        1, rankcounti}] <= bi, Sum[xs[j], {j, 1, rankcounti}] <= k, 
     Table[1 >= xs[j] >= 0, {j, 1, rankcounti}]}]}, 
  xstable \[Element] Integers, MaxIterations -> 10000, 
  Method -> Automatic]

outputFI = FindInstance[
  Flatten[{Sum[
      xs[j]*(Max[ti[[j]] - ((prioritiesi[[j]] - 1) *bmax), 0]), {j, 1,
        rankcounti}] <= bi, Sum[xs[j], {j, 1, rankcounti}] <= k, 
    Table[1 >= xs[j] >= 0, {j, 1, rankcounti}]}], xstable, Integers]

The output:
NMaximize::nsol: There are no points that satisfy the constraints {2.35831 xs[1]+2.51318 xs[2]+1.09651 xs[3]+3.64472 xs[4]+5.87481 xs[8]+3.62432 xs[9]+1.10906 xs[11]<=1.10906,xs[1]+xs[2]+xs[3]+xs[4]+xs[5]+xs[6]+xs[7]+xs[8]+xs[9]+xs[10]+<<1>><=5,1>=xs[1]>=0,1>=xs[2]>=0,1>=xs[3]>=0,1>=xs[4]>=0,1>=xs[5]>=0,1>=xs[6]>=0,1>=xs[7]>=0,1>=xs[8]>=0,<<3>>}.

{-\[Infinity], {xs[1] -> Indeterminate, xs[2] -> Indeterminate, 
  xs[3] -> Indeterminate, xs[4] -> Indeterminate, 
  xs[5] -> Indeterminate, xs[6] -> Indeterminate, 
  xs[7] -> Indeterminate, xs[8] -> Indeterminate, 
  xs[9] -> Indeterminate, xs[10] -> Indeterminate, 
  xs[11] -> Indeterminate}}

{{xs[1] -> 0, xs[2] -> 0, xs[3] -> 0, xs[4] -> 0, xs[5] -> 0, 
  xs[6] -> 0, xs[7] -> 0, xs[8] -> 0, xs[9] -> 0, xs[10] -> 0, 
  xs[11] -> 0}}


k is not defined, so the constraint cannot be satisfied. Once that is fixed, it does appear that this will still have trouble when k<=5. I do not know why though-- probably a bug.

First, there are a small number of points to check, so brute force is a reasonable strategy:
k = 3;
pri = Table[(Max[ti[[j]] - ((prioritiesi[[j]] - 1)*bmax), 0]),
 {j, 1, rankcounti}];
points = Tuples[{0, 1}, rankcounti];
points = 
 Pick[points, 
  And @@ {Max[#] <= 1, # . pri <= bi, Total@# <= k} & /@ 
   points]; points // Length

values = points . vi;
maxpos = Ordering[values, -1];
{Extract[values, maxpos],
 Thread[xstable -> Extract[points, maxpos]]}
(* 
26  (* runs from 6 to 32 as k goes from 1 to rankcounti *)

{2.01176,
 {xs[1] -> 0, xs[2] -> 0, xs[3] -> 0, xs[4] -> 0, xs[5] -> 1,
  xs[6] -> 0, xs[7] -> 1, xs[8] -> 0, xs[9] -> 0, xs[10] -> 1, 
  xs[11] -> 0}}
*)

Second, you can specify initial points for NMinimize like this (I used k=3 as above):
NMaximize[{
  Sum[vi[[j]]  xs[j], {j, 1, rankcounti}],
  Flatten[{Sum[
      xs[j]*(Max[ti[[j]] - ((prioritiesi[[j]] - 1)*bmax), 0]), {j, 1, 
       rankcounti}] <= bi, Sum[xs[j], {j, 1, rankcounti}] <= k, 
    Table[1 >= xs[j] >= 0, {j, 1, rankcounti}]}]
  }, xstable \[Element] Integers, MaxIterations -> 10000,
 Method -> {Automatic, "InitialPoints" -> Take[points, rankcounti + 1]}
 ]
(*
{2.60994,
 {xs[1] -> 0, xs[2] -> 0, xs[3] -> 1, xs[4] -> 0, xs[5] -> 1,
  xs[6] -> 1, xs[7] -> 1, xs[8] -> 0, xs[9] -> 0, xs[10] -> 1, 
  xs[11] -> 0}}
*)

Of course, if Mathematica cannot find the initial points, then you have to be able to find them for this to work.

Did you tryk=3.5 instead of k=3?

For k=3.5  your codes produce {2.01176, {xs[1] -> 0, xs[2] -> 0, xs[3] -> 0, xs[4] -> 0, xs[5] -> 1,    xs[6] -> 0, xs[7] -> 1, xs[8] -> 0, xs[9] -> 0, xs[10] -> 1,    xs[11] -> 0}} and {7.78081, {xs[1] -> 1, xs[2] -> -7, xs[3] -> 1, xs[4] -> 1,    xs[5] -> 1, xs[6] -> 1, xs[7] -> 1, xs[8] -> 1, xs[9] -> 1,    xs[10] -> 1, xs[11] -> 1}}.

Isn't k an integer, @user64494?

Where is that written in the question?

@user64494 Where is it written in the question that it can be 3.5?

The expression Sum[xs[j], {j, 1, rankcounti}] <= k makes sense for real values of k, is not so?

@user64494 Your argument seems weak. The sum is a sum of integers. Think about it.

Then Sum[xs[j], {j, 1, rankcounti}] <= 3.5 is equivalent to Sum[xs[j], {j, 1, rankcounti}] <= 3, is not so?

Quit your caviling, please. It's an integer problem as clearly indicated in the code. Now stop.

Thank you! k is indeed an integer that I forgot to specify, k=5.

Thank you for your comment. It is helpful. Still, it is very strange behavior of NMaximize.
